# Relation between Bootloader, Kernel, Device tree files and Rfs

Tags: kernel, u-boot, device-tree

I would like to understand relationship between these four. Changing on which one of them requires changing in other?
In case my question is not clear; If i make changes on the u-boot configuration, in which others should I make changes?
Thank you

Comment: Your question is rather vague and/or broad for a single accurate answer.  Assuming everything is built for the same hardware platform, then boot programs tend to be quite independent except for source and target specs (what to load from where).  For some ARM machines the Linux kernel and DT must be compiled from the same source version, e.g. Microchip/Atmel DTs are designated as "work in progress" and "unstable".  The rootfs must have a libc and loadable modules that are compatible with the kernel.  *"In case my question is not clear; If i make changes ..."* -- That's still too vague.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sawdust. Sorry i it is not so clear.
I just wanted to learn all requirements/necessary steps to do, to make system boot, work fine, when i customize  rootfs, kernel, bootloader and device tree.